# How can I use Deepin OS's boot disk to delete and merge partitions

Tags: windows, dual-boot, elementary-os

I was dual booting Windows 10 and Elementary OS and decided to overwrite the Elementary OS with Deepin. After installing the Deepin successfully and was trying to restart then no hard disk issue appeared. I can see that I now have too many partitions. How can I delete some of the unwanted partitions? I am desperate now because I want to go into my Windows 10 where development environment is.

Comment: Whenever I put in the Deepin installation usb it gives me access to the disk and its partitions but after successful installation it cannot start when it reboots.